# Escape insert-mode at a particular URL in Vimperator

Tags: firefox, vim, vimperator

Whenever I search for a word in vocabulary.com Vimperator finds the word & put me in the search box & as a result I can't use any vimperator command as I am in insert-mode. I figured out 2 way for avoiding it.

1. Disable insert-mode in vocabulary.com & all its sub-urls.
2. Execute an escape(Esc) key as soon as the url is loaded. (More favourable option)

I have no idea, how to do any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Unfocus all input fields on page load:

```js
autocmd PageLoad .* js blurAllInputFields()
:js << EOF
function blurAllInputFields()
{
    var inputs = window.content.window.document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index)
        inputs[index].blur();
}
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Put these 2 lines in your vimperatorrc:

> autocmd PageLoad .* js document.activeElement.blur();
>
> autocmd PageLoad .*

1st line: clear focus

2nd line: quit Insert mode